# How to call to viewer from other class ?

Tags: java

I created a new plugin in eclipse for view

```
 public class myView extends ViewPart {
   ................... //Show data of files with SWT layout
 }
```

I have also class from other plugin that show files

```
 public class myFile {
         // Data on size of the file , content ....


 }
```

I have an event in the myFile that every time a new the file is created I want to refresh the data in the myView. ( the view should show data on the file )

I don't want to close the view,only to change the data of the view from data on file-1 to data on file-2.

How I can call to the myView from myFile ? is it possible to create the view again ( without close the view )?

It is possible to refresh the data of he view ?

Comment: When building an instance of `myFile`, do you have a pointer to `myView` already? As a side note, you should read about [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: I can add a private member of myView to myFile. I thought because it is ViewPart I need to do something special

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class `myFile`, you should add a constructor with a `myView` parameter, and store it in a private member. Then, whenever some method in `myFile` gets called, you can call any visible methods in `myView`:

```
public class myFile {
    private myView view;

    public myFile (myView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void somethingHappened () {
        view.someMethod ();
    }
}
```

Comment: does it matter if the view is extend from ViewPart ?

Comment: @user1365697 Nope, it doesn't.